# What is the best way to make this code synchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise, dynamic-import

I have the below code where I make an API call and store the response to window. This is done in order to access the value anywhere in the application. But since rest of the application is dependent on this code i want to make this synchronous, that is, rest of the JS should execute only after the api call is done and data is stored to global object. What is the best way to solve this?

Note: This is a sample of the use case. I can't use methods like .then as this is first import in an HTML file having several JS file each of them being dependent on the response of this.

```js
    class GlobalConstants {
      constructor() {
        this.dynamicData = {}; 
        this.getConfigData(); 
      }
 
      async getConfigData() {
        try {
          const configResponse = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
          if (configResponse.status === 200) {
          const dummyData = await configResponse.json();
          this.dynamicUrl = dummyData;
          } else {
            throw new Error(`Config API threw ${formattedConfigResponse.status}`);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.warn("Failed to fetch:", error);
        }
      }
    }
    
window.globalConstants = new GlobalConstants();


console.log(globalConstants.dynamicData)
```

In the example, instead of consoling empty object it should ideally print the api response.

My html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://test.com/script1.js"></script> // This contains the code which I shared
    <script src="https://test.com/script2.js"></script> // This consumes the data. Hence code inside this should execute only after api call and assigment from the previous.
    <script src="https://test.com/script3.js"></script> // This also consumes data from first import
 </head>
<body>
 <div id="body></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: fetch response object has no such property as `.data` have you tried any documentation

Comment: @JaromandaX My bad.  I was doing that based on the original api I was using. Can you check now?

Comment: Let `getConfigData()` take a callback, and call it when things are ready. If there are multiple .js files, you'll have to wrap each file code in a function and call them inside the callback that's passed to `getConfigData()`. If you can't modify the .js files, you can manually include/import them.

Comment: You cannot `await` the constructor of a class. Perhaps you could await `getConfigData` separately after creating the instance. `window.globalConstants = new GlobalConstants(); await window.globalConstants.getConfigData()` (and remove `getConfigData` from the constructor)

Comment: by the way, you can't make asynchronous code synchronous without a tardis or a crystal ball that actually works

Comment: If the code that needs to run after this asynchronous call is in the top level of a JS script, you'll have no choice but to import said file asynchronously with `import()` instead of importing it at the top-level.

Comment: @Kokodoko I don't think we can do that as parent not async

Comment: @Domino The consumption is at the lower levels. This stays at the top.

Comment: Your prototypal async `getConfigData` method does neither assign anything to an instance's own `dynamicData` property, nor does it return any value. But instead it does assign an API response value to an instance's own `dynamicUrl` property. My advice `getConfigData` should never assign anything to an instance's property, but always return a value that can be awaited for.

Comment: In addition, why would one choose a class based abstraction at all. It looks like there will be anyway only just one instance of it with `getConfigData` too, seeing a one time use only. Why not making the latter a single globally or module scoped function which retrieves the data that needs to be awaited. There is no way around `async`/`await`.

Comment: @NeERAJTK ... regarding the updated Q. ... are `script2.js` and `script3.js` 3rd party scripts? Is it possible to provide every resource as js-module? And why is it not an option to import `script2.js` and `script3.js` dynamically?

Comment: @PeterSeliger There are third party scripts as well. Moreover I'll have to make many code changes since there are lot of `this` references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer ...

*"There is no way around [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) syntax, unless one wants to fall back to purely written promises."*

From both of my above comments ...

> Your prototypal async `getConfigData` method does neither assign anything to an instance's own `dynamicData` property, nor does it return any value. But instead it does assign an API response value to an instance's own `dynamicUrl` property. My advice `getConfigData` should never assign anything to an instance's property, but always return a value that can be awaited ...

... e.g. like that ...

```js
class GlobalConstants {
  async getConfigData() {
    let result = {};

    try {
      const configResponse =
        await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");

      if (configResponse.status === 200) {

        result = await configResponse.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Config API threw ${formattedConfigResponse.status}`);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn("Failed to fetch:", error);
    }
    return result;
  }
}

/**
 *  quoted from MDN:
 *
 *  "The await operator is used to wait for a
 *   Promise and get its fulfillment value.
 *   It can only be used inside an async function
 *   or at the top level of a module."
 */
(async() => {

  window.globalConstants = {};

  const configData = await new GlobalConstants().getConfigData();

  Object.assign(window.globalConstants, configData);

  console.log({ globalConstants: window.globalConstants });
  
  // Note.
  //
  // - execute the depended JavaScript code here
  //    - either by invoking an application's `main` or `init` function,
  //    - or by simply pasting all the depended code beneath here,
  //    - or by dynamically importing an/other source/s.

  /* await */import('https://source/path/source-name.js');
})();

// proves the async running code.
console.log({ globalConstants: window.globalConstants });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

> ... In addition, why would one choose a class based abstraction at all. It looks like there will be anyway just one instance of it, with `getConfigData` too, seeing a one time use only. Why not making the latter a single globally or module scoped function which retrieves the data that needs to be awaited. **There is no way around async/await.**

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- This contains the code which was shared in the Q //-->
    <!-- <script src="https://test.com/script1.js"></script> //-->

    <!--
      This consumes the data. Hence code inside this should
      execute only after api call and assigment from the previous.
    //-->
    <!-- <script src="https://test.com/script2.js"></script> //-->

    <!-- This also consumes data from first import //-->
    <!-- <script src="https://test.com/script3.js"></script> //-->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="body"></div>
  <script>

    // instead of  ... <script src="https://test.com/script1.js"><\/script>
    // ... do ...

    async function getConfigData() {
      let result = {};

      try {
        const configResponse =
          await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");

        if (configResponse.status === 200) {

          result = await configResponse.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error(
            `Config API threw ${formattedConfigResponse.status}`
          );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn("Failed to fetch:", error);
      }
      return result;
    }

    (async() => {

      window.globalConstants = {};

      const configData = await getConfigData();

      Object.assign(window.globalConstants, configData);

      console.log({ globalConstants: window.globalConstants });

      // instead of ... 
      // ... <script src="https://test.com/script2.js"><\/script>
      // ... <script src="https://test.com/script3.js"><\/script>
      // ... do ...

      /* await */import('https://test.com/script2.js');

      import("https://test.com/script3.js")
        // .then(module => {
        //   // whatever.
        // })
        // .catch(err => {
        //   // handle error.
        // });

    })();

    // proves the async running code.
    console.log({ globalConstants: window.globalConstants });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above shown/mentioned dynamic import gets achieved via the [*import syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

Comment: Just keep in mind top-level await will not work in older browsers. https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_await_top_level

Comment: Thanks for hinting this again. And because of not having provided actual module based code, and  thus taking exactly this into account, the example comes with the actual code wrapped into an immediately invoked async arrow function expression.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @PeterSeliger. You are right, I think I should stick on to functional approach as it seem to be more ideal for this use case.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I don't want the dependent code to be imported there. I want it be imported in the html file below this js file. So I don't think I will be able to import  inside the async function provided.

Comment: @NeERAJTK ... maybe for what you want it is best to update your example code in order to demonstrate in the most brief/boiled-down way possible how you load/import/provide the sources you want to have executed after the global variables have been assigned.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Sure. I have updated the question.